Nodemailer smtp gmail
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: smtp.gmail.com,
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: harmi********@gmail.com,
            pass: // here i have paste app specific password because i have enable 2MFA,
        },
    });

I am trying to send mail using nodemailer with smtp.gmail.com but It give me below error
{
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n' +
'535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d9443c01a7336-219dc9d4c73sm185321335ad.121 - gsmtp',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
